# Bash: create a report with grep output?

Tags: bash, grep, report

Greetings.

I need to generate a simple report via Bash (Korn?) with this raw data

```
Test_Version=V2.5.2
Test_Version=V2.6.3
Test_Version=V2.4.7
Test_Version=V2.5.2
Test_Version=V2.5.2
Test_Version=V2.5.1
Test_Version=V2.5.0
Test_Version=V2.3.9
Test_Version=V2.3.1
```

Ideally, I'd like to get something like this sorted output

```
Version    Count
...
V2.5.0     1
V2.5.1     1
V2.5.2     3
V2.6.3     1
...
```

I can sort the output like this (raw data is contained in ASCII files):

```
find . -name "*.VER" -exec grep "Test_Version" '{}' ';' -print | grep -e "Test_Version" | sort -u
```

But I can't figure out how to count my records in a tabular layout. Any idea how could I do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a job for [awk](http://people.cs.uu.nl/piet/docs/nawk/nawk_1.html):

Assuming your version information is in the file `versions.txt` (you can also not specify a filename, in that case `awk` reads from stdin).

```
awk -F= '
        {counts[$2]=counts[$2]+1}
END     {for (key in counts)
            printf "%s\t%d\n", key, counts[key]}
' versions.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-F=` tells `awk` to use the `=` character as field separator. Each line in your data will be treated as two fields of which only the second is used.
- The first statement between braces is executed for each line of input. Keeping count for each occurence of the second field, which is `$2`.
- The second statement in braces preceded by the keyword `END` is executed after the last line is processed. It shows all the counts for all distinct values of `$2`.

Comment: This n00b is impressed. Very elegant solution, may I say. Accepted and voted up.

Comment: @Chris: you've mentioned that you'd like to have the output sorted. There's no sorting in that solution.

Comment: I am aware of that: I can deal with it later. This is a minor issue.

Comment: @Chris and @Tomasz Elendt: @Dennis Williamson has sorting in his `awk` solution. Also, you could just pipe through `sort`. I also thought this was a minor issue.

Comment: So then you're doing it wrong. Sorting version numbers is not as simple as that -- you need numeric sort applied on all version number groups (major, minor, build, etc.). So you rather need something like `sort -t\. -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n`. And gawk build-in `asort` is useless in that case because AFAIK it only use its normal rules for comparing values: http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/String-Functions.html

Answer (score 2):

What about something like:

```
$ cat input.txt | sed 's/.*=//' | sort | uniq -c
      1 V2.3.1
      1 V2.3.9
      1 V2.4.7
      1 V2.5.0
      1 V2.5.1
      3 V2.5.2
      1 V2.6.3
```

Can tweak it into the exact format from there...

Answer (score 0):

You won't need any greps:

```
find . -name "*.VER" | 
  awk -F= '
    BEGIN {
      OFS="\t"
    }
    /Test_Version/{
      if (!count[$2]++) ver[num++]=$2
    } 
    END {
      print "Version", "Count"
      n=asort(ver); 
      for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print ver[i], count[ver[i]]
    }'
```